# Create a multi-choice search bar

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to make a simple HTML webpage with a search bar that would be able to query the external search engine of the user's choice (selected in a dropdown menu).

I'm unable to make the user's choice be accepted by the code. Here's what I have:

```html
<html>
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select>
    <option value="http://www.google.com/search">Google</option>
    <option value="http://www.bing.com/search">Bing</option>
    <option value="https://duckduckgo.com/?q=">Duckduckgo</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="search-bar">
  <form method="get" action="???">
    <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:4px;width:20em;">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="q" size="25" maxlength="255" value="" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to use JS to send the users to the selected search engine with his query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with javascript by setting the **`action`** attribute of the **`<form>`** just before the search request is fired.

*Note: this does not work from inside the Stack Overflow snippet for reasons that I can't quite figure out (possibly a Content Security Policy), but I confirmed that it works in a standalone HTML file.*

```js
function UpdateFormAction() {
  var url = document.getElementById("myDropdown").value;
  document.getElementById("myForm").action = url;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select id="myDropdown">
    <option value="http://www.google.com/search">Google</option>
    <option value="http://www.bing.com/search">Bing</option>
    <option value="https://duckduckgo.com/?q=">Duckduckgo</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="search-bar">
  <form id="myForm" target="_blank" method="get" action="???" onsubmit="UpdateFormAction()">
    <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:4px;width:20em;">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="q" size="25" maxlength="255" value="" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not going to be able to do this with only html or css. Your best option is to use javascript to make an api call from the different search engines.

The google search api is [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element).

The bing search api is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-web-search/tutorial-bing-web-search-single-page-app). Note for some features it will cost money.

The duckduckgo search api is [here](https://api.duckduckgo.com/api).

You should also look into Jquery, Asynchronous programming, and JSON. You will most likely be using Jquery's Ajax to request data from each search engine, and will have to be able to parse the json and then change the html with js.

Comment: It doesn't have to be by ajax. It can be by move the user directly to the search page (but JS is needed).

Comment: OP's code snippet made it seem like they want the website to stay on the page and not redirect. I personally would just redirect the page to each search engine, but using ajax to query the results and show them on the same page could work also.

Comment: Yes, but only if the search engine returns the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` did set to `*`.